# Android and Arduino socket

Tags: android, sockets, arduino

I have created a server and client with Android and Arduino but I have a problem. Android reads only one time. Why? this is my code:

Client Android:

```
new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {     
        try {                   
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.240");        
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 8888);
            if(socket == null)System.out.println("SOCKET NULL");
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);
            inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            while(true){
                msgFromServer = inFromServer.readLine();
                System.out.println(msgFromServer);

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                System.out.println("STOP SOCKET");
                // close socket
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Arduino Server:

```
void loop() {

YunClient client = server.accept();
sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);    
String myString = String(sensorValue);

if (client) {
  String command = "none";
  command = client.readString();
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  client.print(myString+"\n");
}
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
    07-24 11:44:24.468: D/OpenGLRenderer(19693): Enabling debug mode 0
07-24 11:44:25.363: I/System.out(19693): 121
```

121 is the value from Arduino. But this is showing only once.

It works only once. I want receive data from the Arduino every second.
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take the accept out of the loop. otherwise it send a string and wait for another connect from client.

```
YunClient client = server.accept();
void loop() {

    sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);    
    String myString = String(sensorValue);

    if (client) {
       String command = "none";
       command = client.readString();
       Serial.println(sensorValue);
       client.print(myString+"\n");
    }
}
```

Also, I don't see where the client sends something to the server. Instead of System.out.println should't it be out.println?